# Script "\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 99" - Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error when debugging code - After flutter update - I have provided the pubspec.yaml below.
Tried  doing flutter clean and flutter pun cache repair.
I suspect it has to do with the dependencies/packages, as I've seen a lot of people complaining about the latest update and dependencies not being combatable.
Please help me out clear this.

```
[  +48 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] 21 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 1 up-to-date
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 19s
```

Here is the pubspecc.yaml file -

```
name: patient_app
description: Grapes IDMR

publish_to: none

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.1.2+19

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2    # => Local storage (small files)
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16       # => Package information (App name..)
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0        # => Flutter widget that automatically resize text to fit perfectly within its bounds.
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.7   # => On boarding Screens slider
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3          # => Toast messages
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0       # => progress Dialogs
  http: ^0.12.0+2               # => for http calls
  sqflite: ^1.0.0               # => Local storage (Large files)
  path_provider: ^1.1.1         # => plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystems.
  #  ext_storage: ^1.0.3   # to get external storage directory
  unique_identifier: ^0.0.3     # => For get unique-ID
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+2        # image picker in profile screen
  image_cropper: ^1.1.0         # crop image in profile screen
  recase: ^2.0.1                # convert string case
  url_launcher: 5.0.2           # launch url in browser
  launch_review: ^2.0.0         # Play store/App store link
  intl: ^0.16.0                 # for locale, datetime format
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.3
  flutter_html: ^0.11.1         # To display html text as page
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.2.2  # for sending email
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.6
  table_calendar: ^2.0.1        # slidable calendar in appointment
  #  speech_to_text: ^0.7.2        # used in clinical notes entry
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+1
  date_format: ^1.0.8
  angles: ^1.2.1                # for tic animation
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  share_extend:                 # for share a file(via social media)
  flutter_html_to_pdf: ^0.5.2   # for pdf export
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1        # for tic sound
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
  file_picker: ^1.5.1    #^1.13.0+1    #^1.9.0+1     # to select file from memory
  photo_view: ^0.9.2    #preview image
  dio: ^3.0.9   #http functions         delete
  mime_type: ^0.3.1   #UPLOAD FILE
  open_file: ^3.0.1
  simple_permissions:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/tq-systems/simple_permissions.git
  #  image: any    #create image thumbnail

  signalr_client: ^0.1.6     # signalr support
  logging: ^0.11.3+2
  w3c_event_source: ^1.0.0
  rxdart : ^0.24.1

  location: ^3.0.0
  overlay_support: ^1.0.4   # for notification over screen
  audio_recorder: ^1.0.2
  proximity_plugin: ^1.0.2
  #  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.1.0    #chat list
  #  audioplayer: ^0.8.1
  #  audioplayer_web: 0.7.1

  app_settings: 4.0.2
  flutter_mailer: ^0.4.1+1
  advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.2.0
  video_player: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/error_icons/
    - assets/images/appointment/
    - assets/audio/
  fonts:
    #    - family: NotoEmoji
    #      fonts:
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
    #          weight: 400
    #    - family: Metropolis
    #      fonts:
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Black.ttf
    #          weight: 900
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-ExtraBold.ttf
    #          weight: 800
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Bold.ttf
    #          weight: 700
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-SemiBold.ttf
    #          weight: 600
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Medium.ttf
    #          weight: 500
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Regular.ttf
    #          weight: 400
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Light.ttf
    #          weight: 300
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-ExtraLight.ttf
    #          weight: 200
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Metropolis-Thin.ttf
    #          weight: 100
    #    - family: RobotoRegular
    #      fonts:
    #        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
    - family: SourceCodePro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Semibold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/SourceCodePro-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 200
  #    - family: AppIcons
  #      fonts:
  #        - asset: assets/fonts/AppIcons.ttf
  #          weight: 600


  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the latest update of Flutter. I have also faced some problems. This is what I did to resolve.

- If you are running your flutter project in the `stable` channel, then I would recommend using either the `beta` or the `master` channel. To change your flutter channel open your terminal and write: `flutter channel beta` OR `flutter channel master`. Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter run`.
- If the above method also doesn't work then you should definitely work with some older version of the flutter. Simply write downgrade your flutter by writing `flutter downgrade` in your terminal.

Comment: Deleting the pubspec.lock and running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub` get also solved the problem for me.